# Rules for Carrying flammable subtances in UK

Tags: fire, trekking, uk

I am planning for a trek in Northern and Eastern parts of England. I am planning to cover the Hull to Liverpool section of [the Trans Pennine Trail](http://www.transpenninetrail.org.uk/), which is roughly 290 km or 180 miles.

I have managed and planned for accommodation and camp-sites. As the weather in England is rainy most of the time of the year, I need a way to set-up a bonfire if I am allowed to. In India, we have a lot of restrictions on carrying flammable substances like Kerosene, Rockel, etc.

Are there any restrictions in England about carrying them? Whats the best organization or local body to fetch that information?

Comment: do not carry liquid fuel to help you start a fire. Whether it's legal or not, it's impractical. The day's newspaper and a small amount of dry twigs should be all you need, and are far safer. I've started many a rainy-day fire without resorting to flammable liquids.

Comment: My experience lines up with Kate's - it's just unnecessary. You should be able to keep the fire sheltered while it's building up even if it is raining, then when it's established the rain shouldn't douse it beyond usefulness.

Comment: Additionally, despite the myths, it is more often not-rainy than rainy. Check to see if all areas allow fires - some don't due to risk of wildfire. Yes, even in the UK.

Comment: Starting fires with flammable liquids is not something I would want to do in the wilderness away from all possible safety personnel and equipment.

Comment: @RoryAlsop: Oh. I always was under impression that it always rains in UK. So to set up a small bonfire for keeping me warm, I thought I would need something like a Kerosene..

Comment: No, it does not rain constantly in the UK...? This obviously depends, but the average rainfall for Liverpool (where I live) is 144 days a year, so **39%** of the days it will rain. http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/public/weather/climate/gcmzggpxq

Comment: Maybe consider a storm kettle? I've used mine many a time when I didn't want to set a full camp fire & hot drinks are a real godsend after a wet days walk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't a problem carrying fuel for camping stoves (assuming in "sensible" quanities) in the UK.

**HOWEVER**, when wild camping (i.e camping off of organised camp sites) in the UK, the ethos is to leave no trace afterwards. So setting camp fires is a no-no. And on many organised camp sites, open fires are forbidden (although some do allow small fires and may supply a metal container for this purpose but in my experience, these are in the minority).